# Removing ' &raquo; ' from a String using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<div id="bread"></div>` and I am trying to display breadcrumbs where one of the string contains `Tab3 »`.

Its like `Tab1` > `Tab2` > `Tab3 »` > `Tab4` except that `>` is an `arrow-right.png` image.

I want to remove `&raquo` or `»` from `Tab3 »`.

I want to search if the selected tab has `»` or `&raquo` in it and if it does then I want to replace it with `""` so that `Tab3 »` becomes `Tab3`.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var crumbs = $("a.selected");

    jQuery.each(crumbs, function() {

        if(this != crumbs.get([0])) {
            $("#bread").append("&nbsp;");           
        }           
        $("#bread").append("<img src='<c:url value="/resources/images/arrow-right.png" />' />" + "&nbsp;");

            var crumb = $(this).html();
            var slicedCrumb;
            if(crumb.indexOf(' &raquo; ') != -1) {
                slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace(' &raquo; ', '');              
                $("#bread").append(slicedCrumb);
            }
            else {
                $("#bread").append(crumb);
            }

     });
});
```

I also tried to use `»` at the place of `&raquo;` but that din't seem to work either.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var crumbs = $("a.selected");

    jQuery.each(crumbs, function() {

        if(this != crumbs.get([0])) {
            $("#bread").append("&nbsp;");           
        }           
        $("#bread").append("<img src='<c:url value="/resources/images/arrow-right.png" />' />" + "&nbsp;");

            var crumb = $(this).html();
            var slicedCrumb;
            if(crumb.indexOf(' » ') != -1) {
                slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace(' » ', '');                
                $("#bread").append(slicedCrumb);
            }
            else {
                $("#bread").append(crumb);
            }

     });
});
```

I've spent quite sometime reading other posts on the given subject but somehow I am not able to get it working. Could someone help me understand what am I missing here? I am using `jquery-1.5.js` to run this code. Do I need to use the newer version of `jquery` or any other library as well to get it working?

Comment: If you could make a JSfiddle with the HTML and the JS you tried, that would make helping you a lot easier.

Comment: Is the value with the `»` coming from a source that you control (e.g., CMS)?  Perhaps you could save yourself a lot of effort by sanitizing the data at the source.

Comment: @saratis: I din't know what JSfiddle mean before but after googling it I think I could try to do that. Thanks. I know very little about JavaScript and jquery.

Comment: @Pheonix: I understood that wrong when I first read your comment. No, those Tabs are simple menu tabs while ` » ` is being appended dynamically from another javascript which appens ` » ` to any Tab that has subtabs as well. If I change that value from ` » ` to ` > ` I am able to solve that problem. But I want to use ` » ` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace(/\»/g, '');
```

The important part is escaping the `»` character. Also I added the global (`g`) flag so that if there are multiple instances that match the regex, they will all be removed.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YXXZs/1/

**UPDATE**

If you want to check if a character exists before trying to replace it then you can use `.match()`:

```
var text = $(this).html();
if (text.search(/\»/) > -1) {
    slicedCrumb = text.replace(/\»/g, '');
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YXXZs/4/

Docs for `.match()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: `   if(crumb.indexOf('\»') != -1) {
    slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace(/\»/g, '');    
    $("#bread").append(slicedCrumb);
   }` is not working. How do I test if the element in crumbs array has ` » ` in it?

Comment: `crumb.search('\»') != -1` or `crumb.search(/\»/) != -1`don't work either. I am not sure if the expressions I've used are right. I am new to javascript or jquery.

Comment: @skip `if (crumb.search(/\»/) > -1){...}` should work, check-out the demo I posted in the **update** to my answer.

Comment: `if (crumb.search(/\»/) > -1){...}` is not working either :(.  I tried your demo but that ain't working either. If I changed the dynamically appending ` » ` to `" > "` and then search for it and then replace it with `""` everything works alright. But I want to use ` » ` instead to display a tab that has subtabs. Did you mean I could use `match()` at the place of `search()`? I tried that as well but that doesn't work either.

Comment: If I replace `" &raquo "` with ` &gt; ` in the dynamically appending code for tabs that have subtabs and use `  if((crumb.indexOf(" &gt; ") > -1)) {
    slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace(' &gt; ', '');   
    $("#bread").append(slicedCrumb);
   }` everything works just fine and the appended `Tab3 > ` gets converted to `Tab3` in the `bread` div. But I want tabs that have subtabs to be displayed like `Tab3 » ` which is causing the problem.

Comment: @skip I tested my demo in six major browsers and it works as expected in all of them, what error do you get when using this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YXXZs/4/ ?

Comment: I've been using the tabs being discussed in this question coupled with http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started. And All I could think of is that this other superfish plugin has been having some issue while integrating with these tabs. These tabs are using a different javascript to create dropdownmenu than superfish plugin. superfish tabs couldnt be used with another superfish tabs and caused some issue was the reason why I used some other dropdownmenu script linked with superfish tabs. Now I am thinking of removing the superfish tabs altogether.

Comment: I don't see any problems with your code snippet as its working here as well but unfortunately not while being coupled with superfish. I will remove superfish and simply use just one script for all the linked tabs and drop the result in case it works. There are actually 4 levels of tabs at different locations of the page. I am checking your answer as I think its right.

Comment: No matter what I do `»` is not being removed while `>` or anything else disappears easily. I've removed the superfish plugin and using only one dropdownscript.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace('/[&]raquo[;]/ ', '');
```

Comment: `   if(crumb.indexOf('/[&]raquo[;]/') != -1) {
    slicedCrumb = $(this).html().replace('/[&]raquo[;]/ ', '');    
    $("#bread").append(slicedCrumb);
   }` is not working either :(.